# Google Cloud VM SSH No supported authentication methods available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I have a Google cloud VM instance with Debian OS. I have hosted Wordpress sites. After upgrading OS version all was working fine and I was able to connect via SSH using 'Open SSH in browser' option.

Now I try to connect my VM instance using 'Open SSH in browser' it just keep retrying. I checked the serial console output but there is no error message. Please refer below
[image]

However, I am able to connect via FTP using same key but when I try to connect via SSH at that time facing the issue. I checked for port 22 for that instance and project and it's open
[image]

Below is the Last few lines of serial console log after I restarted the VM,

```
Dec  6 09:01:20 localhost sendmail[383]: Starting Mail Transport Agent (MTA): sendmail.
Dec  6 09:01:20 localhost systemd[1]: Started LSB: powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent.
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3.31 database server.
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical InterfacDec  6 09:01:21 localhost systemd[1]: Startup finished in 4.063s (kernel) + 9.852s (userspace) = 13.915s.
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[567]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[570]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[570]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[570]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[570]: Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[570]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[570]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[580]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Dec  6 09:01:21 localhost debian-start[564]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Debian GNU/Linux 10 localhost ttyS0

localhost login: Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 110...
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Stopped target Default.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Stopped target Basic System.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Stopped target Timers.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Stopped target Paths.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Stopped target Sockets.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: gpg-agent-browser.socket: Succeeded.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: dirmngr.socket: Succeeded.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: gpg-agent-ssh.socket: Succeeded.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: gpg-agent.socket: Succeeded.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: gpg-agent-extra.socket: Succeeded.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Reached target Shutdown.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: systemd-exit.service: Succeeded.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Started Exit the Session.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[497]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[1]: user@110.service: Succeeded.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 110.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/110...
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[1]: run-user-110.mount: Succeeded.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@110.service: Succeeded.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/110.
Dec  6 09:01:28 localhost systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 110.
```

Tried following solutions which I get from google search

**Solution 1 : Using PuTTYGen & Putty**

Generated key using PuttyGen and put the public key under meta data as well tried adding under instance. I have set `enable-oslogin` to `FALSE`.
But got the following error message.
[image]

**Solution 2 : Using serial ports**

When I tried to connect using diff serial ports it just stack at connection screen and I checked the console log for that serial port but it's blank.
[image]

**Solution 3 : New Instance with disk image**

Created image of current disk and then created new instance with that image. When I try to connect to that new instance then I am facing same issue.

**Solution 4 : Use diff machine to setup CLI**

I setup fresh Google Cloud CLI into a new machine and tried to connect but no success. Same error I faced.

**Solution 5 : Increase Disk Space**

Increased the disk space from 20GB to 35GB, but didn't work. Usually if there is disk space error the we get it into serial console log. But in my case there is no error message in serial console log.

Please help and let me know if any additional information is required.
Thanks

Comment: Can you try the [troubleshooting ssh](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) steps and let me know if this solves your problem or not?

Comment: Tip: for the serial port screen, the process is waiting for input. Press ENTER. however, if you previously did not set logins, then you will only be able to review output. This is useful to watch an SSH login on the server side.

Comment: @BakulMitra This is the output of trubleshoot command https://prnt.sc/225kiqv . This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried pressing ENTER but it didn't proceed. I might be not using it proper way. Please guide

Comment: Related issue with metadata-based keys not working in Ubuntu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328011/google-cloud-vm-metadata-based-keys-ssh-handshake-failed-unable-to-authenticate