# Google Cloud VM metadata-based keys ssh: handshake failed unable to authenticate and oslogin_cache_refresh: Failure getting groups, quitting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys, cloud-init

When trying to SSH to GCE VMs using [metadata-based SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#metadata) I get the following error:

```
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

While troubleshooting I can see the keys in the instance metadata, but they are not being added to the user's authorized_keys file:

```
$ curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/ssh-keys"
username:ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC....omitted....
admin:ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC....omitted....


$ sudo ls -hal /home/**/.ssh/
/home/ubuntu/.ssh/:
total 8.0K
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Aug 11 23:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Aug 11 23:19 ..
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Aug 11 23:19 authorized_keys
# Only result is the default zero-length file for ubuntu user
```

I also see the following errors in the ssh server auth log and [Google Guest Environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment) services:

```
$ sudo less /var/log/auth.log
Aug 11 23:28:59 test-vm sshd[2197]: Invalid user admin from 1.2.3.4 port 34570
Aug 11 23:28:59 test-vm sshd[2197]: Connection closed by invalid user admin 1.2.3.4 port 34570 [preauth]

$ sudo journalctl -u google-guest-agent.service
Aug 11 22:24:42 test-vm oslogin_cache_refresh[907]: Refreshing passwd entry cache
Aug 11 22:24:42 test-vm oslogin_cache_refresh[907]: Refreshing group entry cache
Aug 11 22:24:42 test-vm oslogin_cache_refresh[907]: Failure getting groups, quitting
Aug 11 22:24:42 test-vm oslogin_cache_refresh[907]: Failed to get groups, not updating group cache file, removing /etc/oslogin_group.cache.bak.

# or
Aug 11 23:19:37 test-vm GCEGuestAgent[766]: 2022-08-11T23:19:37.6541Z GCEGuestAgent Info: Creating user admin.
Aug 11 23:19:37 test-vm useradd[885]: failed adding user 'admin', data deleted
Aug 11 23:19:37 test-vm GCEGuestAgent[766]: 2022-08-11T23:19:37.6869Z GCEGuestAgent Error non_windows_accounts.go:144:
  Error creating user: useradd: group admin exists - if you want to add this user to that group, use -g.
```

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the latest cloud-init and guest-oslogin packages for **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (focal)** seem to have an issue that causes **google-guest-agent.service** to exit before completing its task. The issue was [fixed](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-oslogin/issues/50) and [committed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-guest-agent/+bug/1959392) but not yet released for focal (and likely other Ubuntu versions).

For now you can try disabling [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin#gcloud) by setting instance or project metadata `enable-oslogin=FALSE`. After which you should see the expected results and be able to SSH using those keys:

```
$ sudo journalctl -u google-guest-agent.service
Aug 11 23:10:33 test-vm GCEGuestAgent[761]: 2022-08-11T23:10:33.0517Z GCEGuestAgent Info: Created google sudoers file
Aug 11 23:10:33 test-vm GCEGuestAgent[761]: 2022-08-11T23:10:33.0522Z GCEGuestAgent Info: Creating user username.
Aug 11 23:10:33 test-vm useradd[881]: new group: name=username, GID=1002
Aug 11 23:10:33 test-vm useradd[881]: new user: name=username, UID=1001, GID=1002, home=/home/username, shell=/bin/bash, from=none
Aug 11 23:10:33 test-vm gpasswd[895]: user username added by root to group ubuntu
Aug 11 23:10:33 test-vm gpasswd[904]: user username added by root to group adm
Aug 11 23:10:33 test-vm gpasswd[983]: user username added by root to group google-sudoers
Aug 11 23:10:33 test-vm GCEGuestAgent[761]: 2022-08-11T23:10:33.7615Z GCEGuestAgent Info: Updating keys for user username.

$ sudo ls -hal /home/username/.ssh/
/home/username/.ssh/:
total 12K
drwx------ 2 username username 4.0K Aug 11 23:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 username username 4.0K Aug 11 23:35 ..
-rw------- 1 username username  589 Aug 11 23:19 authorized_keys
```

The `admin` user however will not work, since it conflicts with an existing linux group. You should pick a username that does not conflict with any of the **name:x:123:** names listed at `getent group`